# Fit easyui datagrid column to the available width

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

In the below code, There are 3 columns specified in **%** except for the last, of those I need **menu3** to occupy the available width.

**HTML**

```
<table id="dg" style="width:100%;height:100%">
   <thead>
      <tr height="20">
         <th data-options="field:'menu1',sortable:false,resizable:false" width="20%">Menu1</th>
         <th data-options="field:'menu2',sortable:false,resizable:false" width="20%">menu2</th>
         <th data-options="field:'menu3',sortable:false,resizable:false" width="">menu3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    var dg = $('#dg').edatagrid();
    dg.edatagrid({
        fit:true,
        fitColumns: true,   
    });
});
```

This is the fiddle which I have tried so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/0hk1twng/157/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just add following css. it will make table width to 100%

```
.datagrid-btable, .datagrid-header-inner, .datagrid-htable {
   width : 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. with this, all the columns assigned with **%** were expanding. I want the only column (**menu3**) to be expanded which has unassigned width.